# ifstream failing to open files in XCode even with full path[SOLVED]

Tags: c++, xcode

I am trying to get my C++ driven OpenGL working in a Cocoa app. In order to have everything in one place I need to load my shader and textures files in my C++. I'm doing that with std::ifstream, which fails to open files for some reason.

I have had a similar problem in the past when in order for XCode to open files you need to add them to the project and then do one of 3 things:

1) Copy them to Products Directory on the build phase

2) Change your Working directory in your scheme

3) Just use the full file path

However in my recent project neither have helped. The most interesting thing is in a very similar project(basically the project where I tried and tested everything it did work). I suppose I didn't move all the project settings over, but everything seems the same.

The only difference between them is that the one I'm working on now has more Objective-C in it.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <QuartzCore/CVDisplayLink.h>
#import "Application.hpp"
@interface viewObj : NSOpenGLView {
    CVDisplayLinkRef displayLink;
    Application* appInstance;
}
@end

@implementation viewObj

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    appInstance = new Application();
    // other GL initializing code
}
@end
```

Application.hpp

```
#include "appView.hpp"
class Application {
private:
    appView  viewInstance{};
public:
    Application();
    void update();
    ~ Application();
};
```

appView.hpp

```
class appView {
private:
    bool graphical;
    GLuint texture;
    int screenWidth, screenHeight;
    Shader shader{"full_path/core.vs", "full_path/core.frag"};
    std::vector<GLfloat> vert;
}
```

Shader.hpp

```
class Shader {
public:
    GLuint Program;

    Shader(const std::string& vertexPath, const std::string& fragmentPath)
    {
        std::string vertexCode;
        std::string fragmentCode;
        std::ifstream vShaderFile;
        std::ifstream fShaderFile;
        vShaderFile.exceptions (std::ifstream::badbit);
        fShaderFile.exceptions (std::ifstream::badbit);
        try
        {
            vShaderFile.open(vertexPath.c_str(), std::ios::in);// Failing here
            if (!vShaderFile.is_open()) {
                throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Failed to open shader file: ") + std::string(vertexPath));
            }

            fShaderFile.open(fragmentPath.c_str(), std::ios::in);
            if (!fShaderFile.is_open()) {
                throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Failed to open shader file: ") + std::string(fragmentPath));
            }

            std::stringstream vShaderStream, fShaderStream;

            vShaderStream << vShaderFile.rdbuf();
            vShaderStream << "\0";
            fShaderStream << fShaderFile.rdbuf();
            fShaderStream << "\0";

            vShaderFile.close();
            fShaderFile.close();

            vertexCode = vShaderStream.str( );
            fragmentCode = fShaderStream.str( );
        }
        catch ( std::ifstream::failure e )
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FILE_NOT_SUCCESFULLY_READ" << std::endl;
        }

        const GLchar *vShaderCode = (const GLchar *)vertexCode.c_str();
        const GLchar *fShaderCode = (const GLchar *)fragmentCode.c_str();

        // Compile shaders
        GLuint vertex, fragment;
        GLint success;
        GLchar infoLog[512];
        // Vertex Shader
        vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertex, 1, &vShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vertex);

        glGetShaderiv(vertex, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
        }

        // Fragment Shader
        fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragment, 1, &fShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fragment);

        glGetShaderiv(fragment, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
        }

        // Shader Program
        this->Program = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(this->Program, vertex);
        glAttachShader(this->Program, fragment);
        glLinkProgram(this->Program);

        glGetProgramiv(this->Program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success)
        {
            glGetProgramInfoLog(this->Program, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
        }


        glDeleteShader(vertex);
        glDeleteShader(fragment);

    }
    // Uses the current shader
    void Use() const {
        glUseProgram(this->Program);
    }
};
```

Apparently the problem was with my app not having access to any files due to sandbox mode, which I disabled in .entitlements and that fixed the problem

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: @RichardCritten doing that helped in the test project. This one doesn't open files even with full paths

Comment: @AlanBirtles added some code, should give a general idea of what I am trying to do

Comment: `"full_path/core.vs"` is a relative path not an absolute path, please post a [mre]